# How to create an instance of a generic class in Java?

Tags: java

I have this big problem on my code that I can't create an instance of my generic class :(
My goal was a server, that can handle different kinds of Client-Sockets.

```
public class Server<T extends AClientSocket> implements Runnable{
//... some other code
private void newClient() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("[SERVER] Auf neuen Client warten...");
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    clients.add(new T(clientSocket)); //Compile Error :(
    new Thread((clients.get(clients.size()-1))).start();
}
//... some more code
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Server<ClientSocketHTTP> server = new Server<ClientSocketHTTP>(8000);
    //... different code
}
}
```

"AClientSocket" is an abstract class with a defined constructor.

**The Solution:**

```
//... some code
private final Function<Socket, T> clientCreator;
public Server(int port, Function<Socket, T> clientCreator) throws Exception
{
    PORT = port;
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    sockets = new ArrayList<T>();
    this.clientCreator = clientCreator;
}
//... some code
private void newClient() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("[SERVER] Auf neuen Client warten...");
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("[SERVER] Client gefunden...");
    sockets.add(clientCreator.apply(clientSocket));
    new Thread((sockets.get(sockets.size()-1))).start();
    System.out.println("[SERVER] Client hinzugefügt...");
}
//... some code
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Server<ClientSocketHTTP> server = new Server<ClientSocketHTTP>(8000, clientSocket -> {
        try {
            return new ClientSocketHTTP(clientSocket);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.exit(0);
            return null;
        }
    });
//... code
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't, and `new`ing up instances like this is the source of all sorts of design headaches. Instead, pass a `Function<Socket, T>` to the class, and have `newClient()` call `clientCreator.apply(clientSocket)`. If the implementation is as simple as creating a new instance, you can just pass `ClientSocketHttp::new`.

Comment: Given the OP's code, it looks like they want a `Function<Socket, T>`, not a `Supplier<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! What do you mean with "clientCreator.apply(clientSocket)"? Could you explain me more about that? Would appreciate! :)

Comment: @AlwinBrauns If the answer solved your problem, mark it as "accepted" by clicking the green checkmark on the left and optionally clicking the up arrow.

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow and if it worked I will do that! Thanks

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- 
`private class ClientSocketCreator implements Function<Socket, T>`
 `{`

  `@Override`
  `public T apply(Socket arg0) {`
   `return null; // How??? I want (new T(arg0))`
  `}`
  
  
 `}`
 
 `private void newClient() throws Exception`
 `{`
  `System.out.println("[SERVER] Auf neuen Client warten...");`
  `Socket client = serverSocket.accept();`
  `clientSocket.add(clientCreator.apply(client));`
  `new Thread((clientSocket.get(clientSocket.size()-1))).start();`
 `}`

Sorry for the formatting im new here xD

Comment: ```public T apply(Socket arg0) {
   return null; // How??? I want (new T(arg0))
  }```

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Sorry I think you missunderstood "clientSocket". This is just an ArrayList<T>

I've updated this in my question

Comment: @AlwinBrauns I didn't quite misunderstand, but I'll edit your question to fix misleading naming.

Comment: @chryslis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks. Yes my naming was a bit confusing. It's a learning project and the code isn't optimized for others to read. I don't get it how to use your advice. I really tried a lot of different things with the Function but I seem to not get it to work. It's seems to me like a design mistake of mine but still would be interesting how I get it to work.

Comment: @AlwinBrauns You do not need a `class implements Function<Socket, T>`. Just pass `ClientSocketHttp::new` to the constructor for `Server`; Java understands to use this method as the implementation for the single-method interface.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!! Everything makes sense now. @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-